# How to use multiprocessing Value to pass image base64 string?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

on a project of mine I try to run Figure.savefig() on seperate multiprocessing.Process (due memory leak) but I am don't manage to allocate shared variable long enough for passing the image string.

See concept example:

```
import base64
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def my_func(shared_string):
    with open("image.png", "rb") as image_file:
       
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
        shared_string.value = encoded_string.decode()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shared_string = Value('c', b'\0'*1024*1024) # Allocate 1MB of memory for the string
    print("Before:", shared_string.value)

    p = Process(target=my_func, args=(shared_string,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print("After:", shared_string.value)
```

But I receive errors, probably because I don't understand how to set the args properly

```
  File "C:\Users\MyName\MyFiles\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    shared_string = Value('c', b'\0'*1024*1024) # Allocate 1MB of memory for the string
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 135, in Value
    return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, lock=lock,
  File "C:\Users\MyName\miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 74, in Value
    obj = RawValue(typecode_or_type, *args)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 51, in RawValue
    obj.__init__(*args)
TypeError: one character bytes, bytearray or integer expected
```

I also tried to use multiprocessing.Array instead, but the image string size exceed over the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. a Value is for storing a single number, you are looking for an `Array` instead.
2. for arrays you need to use the `array.raw` attribute instead of `array.value`.
3. only `bytes` arrays can be stored in a fixed size array, a unicode string cannot be stored in a bytes array because it doesn't have a fixed size (a unicode character can take up more than one byte), `decode()` converts between `bytes` and `str`, this is probably not what you want to do, if you really must send a unicode string you are better off using `multiprocessing.Queue`.
4. just note you only need `b64encode` if you are sending it over `http`.

the following modification to your code shows how it can be done.

```py
 import base64
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array


def my_func(shared_string):
    with open("my_file", "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
        shared_string.raw = encoded_string


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # write data to file, to make sure it is there
    with open("my_file",'wb') as f:
        orig_string = b"1"*8
        encoded_string = base64.b64decode(orig_string)
        f.write(encoded_string)

    shared_string = Array('c', b'\0' * len(orig_string))  # Allocate 8 bytes of memory for the string
    print("Before:", shared_string.raw)

    p = Process(target=my_func, args=(shared_string,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print("After:", shared_string.raw)
```

Comment: HI @AhmedAEK, your answer was really helpful after I did small change.

from some reason, when you set 
**shared_string.raw = encoded_string**
it actually been set to "shared_string.value" - so by the end I printed **shared_string.value**

second question, Do I need to close/clear/release the Array variable from memory after the use?

Comment: @Nitcha the array is reference counted, it will automatically be garbage collected when both processes can no-longer access it when it goes out of scope.